# ¿Por qué mi menú se visualiza por detrás de los elementos a pesar de tener un z-index mayor?

Tags: html, css

Tengo mi hamburguer menu, puesto que está creado en mobile first, el z-index es mayor a los elementos donde empieza la imagen más grande con la superposición de otros elementos, el punto es que a pesar de que el menú tenga mayor z-index, la imagen grande y la superposición que le sigue se muestran por detrás de toda la página pero el texto de la superposición ya no es seleccionable como la parte que dice **Moden Interior** donde el cursor se muestra para seleccionar texto.

```js
mostrarNav = () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('header__navigation__hamburguer')[0].classList.toggle('active');
};
```

```css
/* FONTS */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200&family=Lora:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
/* VARIABLES */
/* FUNCTIONS*/
/* GLOBAL RESETS */
* {
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}

html {
    font-size : 62.5%;
}

body {
    background-color : #181719;
}

a {
    text-decoration : none;
}

ul {
    list-style : none;
}

/* HEADING STYLES */
h1 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Crimson Pro', serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 200;
}

h2 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Lora', serif;
    font-size   : 3.6rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

h3 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.2rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

h4 {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Lora', serif;
    font-size   : 1.8rem;
    font-weight : 700;
}

h5 {
    color       : #A9A9A9;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

p {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 400;
}

.container {
    margin    : 0 auto;
    max-width : 37.5rem;
    width     : 90%;
}

/* HEADER */
/*.header {
  padding-top : 1.9rem;

  &__container {

  }

  &__menu__container {
    align-items     : center;
    display         : flex;
    justify-content : space-between;
    position        : relative;

    & h1 {
      border         : 1px solid $white;
      padding        : .8rem;
      text-transform : uppercase;
    }
  }

  &__hamburguer {
    position         : fixed;
    top              : -9px;
    left             : 0;
    width            : 100%;
    height           : 100%;
    background-color : $background;
    cursor           : pointer;
    z-index          : 200;
    clip-path        : circle(25px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
    transition       : all 300ms ease-in-out;

    &.active {
      clip-path : circle(75%);
    }

    &__button {
      position : absolute;
      top      : 2rem;
      right    : 2rem;
      width    : 5rem;
      height   : 5rem;
      cursor   : pointer;

      & span {
        background-color : $white;
        position         : absolute;
        left             : 50%;
        transform        : translate(-50%, -50%);
        width            : 50%;
        height           : .2rem;
        transition       : all 200ms ease-in-out;

        &:nth-child(1) {
          top : 30%;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
          top : 50%;
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
          top : 70%;
        }
      }

    }

    &-links {
      text-align : center;
      position   : absolute;
      top        : 50%;
      left       : 50%;
      transform  : translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    & a {
      @include heading-styles($white, $montserrat, 1.8rem, 500);
      border-bottom  : 2px solid transparent;
      padding-bottom : .6rem;

      &:hover {
        @include heading-styles($white, $montserrat, 1.8rem, 700);
        transition     : all 300ms ease-in-out;
        border-bottom  : 2px solid white;
        padding-bottom : .6rem;
      }
    }

    &-link {
      margin-bottom : 3.2rem;
    }
  }
}

.header__hamburguer.active .header__hamburguer__button span:nth-child(1) {
  top       : 50%;
  transform : translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.header__hamburguer.active .header__hamburguer__button span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity : 0;
}

.header__hamburguer.active .header__hamburguer__button span:nth-child(3) {
  top       : 50%;
  transform : translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}*/
/* HEADER */
.header {
    margin-bottom : 3.8rem;
    padding-top   : 1.9rem;
}

.header__menu__container {
    align-items     : center;
    justify-content : space-between;
    display         : flex;
}

.header__menu__container h1 {
    border         : 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding        : 0.8rem;
    text-transform : uppercase;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer {
    align-items : center;
    cursor      : pointer;
    display     : flex;
    position    : relative;
    z-index     : 2;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer span {
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    display          : block;
    height           : 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom    : 0.3rem;
    position         : relative;
    transition       : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width            : 3rem;
    z-index          : 1;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
    background-color : #181719;
    clip-path        : circle(40px at calc(50% + (37.5rem / 2) - (40px / 2)) calc(0% + 1.9rem + (40px / 2)));
    height           : 100%;
    left             : 0;
    opacity          : 0;
    position         : absolute;
    top              : 0;
    transition       : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    visibility       : hidden;
    width            : 100%;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer.active + .header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
    clip-path  : circle(100%);
    opacity    : 1;
    visibility : visible;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 50%;
    left       : 50%;
    transform  : translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align : center;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link {
    margin-bottom : 2rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a {
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    font-family    : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size      : 1.8rem;
    font-weight    : 500;
    border-bottom  : 2px solid transparent;
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom : 0.6rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a:hover {
    color          : #FFFFFF;
    font-family    : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size      : 1.8rem;
    font-weight    : 700;
    border-bottom  : 2px solid white;
    padding-bottom : 0.6rem;
    transition     : all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.line {
    fill         : none;
    stroke       : #FFFFFF;
    stroke-width : 6;
    transition   : stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.line1 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 207;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.line2 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 60;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.line3 {
    stroke-dasharray : 60 207;
    stroke-width     : 6;
}

.active .line1 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset : -134;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}

.active .line2 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 1 60;
    stroke-dashoffset : -30;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}

.active .line3 {
    stroke-dasharray  : 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset : -134;
    stroke-width      : 6;
}

/* MAIN */
.main__information__details {
    margin-bottom : 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details h2 {
    margin-bottom : 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details p {
    margin-bottom : 2.5rem;
    max-width     : 25rem;
}

.main__information__details__button {
    display : inline-block;
}

.main__information__details__button a {
    color       : #FFFFFF;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1.4rem;
    font-weight : 700;
    align-items : center;
    display     : flex;
}

.main__information__details__button a span {
    margin-left : 1.5rem;
}

.main__information__product {
    display               : grid;
    position              : relative;
    grid-template-columns : repeat(13, 1fr);
    z-index               : -1;
}

.main__information__product__image {
    grid-column : 1/-1;
    grid-row    : 1;
}

.main__information__product__image img {
    width : 100%;
}

.main__information__product__box {
    margin-top  : -20%;
    box-shadow  : 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background  : #181719;
    width       : 100%;
    grid-column : 3/13;
    padding     : 1.317rem 0 2.5rem 1.9rem;
}

.main__information__product__person {
    align-items   : center;
    display       : flex;
    margin-bottom : 1.824rem;
}

.main__information__product__person img {
    height        : 3.6rem;
    width         : 3.6rem;
    border-radius : 50%;
    margin-right  : 1.39rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details h3 {
    margin-bottom : 0.585rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details p {
    color       : #828282;
    font-family : 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size   : 1rem;
    font-weight : 500;
}

.main__information__product h4 {
    max-width : 21rem;
    width     : 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
              content="ie=edge">
        <title>Interior Consultant</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon"
              href="devchallenges.png"
              type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
              rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <!--<header class="header">
            <div class="header__container container">
                <div class="header__menu__container">
                    <h1>This Interior</h1>
                    <div class="header__hamburguer"
                         onclick="mostrarNav()">
                        <div class="header__hamburguer__button">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="header__hamburguer-links">
                                <li class="header__hamburguer-link">
                                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__hamburguer-link">
                                    <a href="#">Collection</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__hamburguer-link">
                                    <a href="#">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__hamburguer-link">
                                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </header>-->
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header__container container">
                <div class="header__menu__container">
                    <h1>This Interior</h1>
                    <div class="header__navigation">
                        <div class="header__navigation__hamburguer "
                             onclick="mostrarNav()">
                            <svg width="40"
                                 height="40"
                                 viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                                <path class="line line1"
                                      d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058"/>
                                <path class="line line2"
                                      d="M 20,50 H 80"/>
                                <path class="line line3"
                                      d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942"/>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <nav class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu">
                            <ul class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links">
                                <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                                    <a class="link-social"
                                       href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                                    <a class="link-social"
                                       href="#">Collection</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                                    <a class="link-social"
                                       href="#">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                                    <a class="link-social"
                                       href="#">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="main">
            <div class="main__information container">
                <div class="main__information__details">
                    <h2>Modern Interior</h2>
                    <p>A full-Service residential & commercial interior design and staging company offering professional
                       organizing & eco-services.</p>
                    <div class="main__information__details__button">
                        <a href="#">Read more <span class="material-icons">trending_flat</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main__information__product">
                    <figure class="main__information__product__image">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1474/1100"
                             alt="">
                    </figure>
                    <div class="main__information__product__box">
                        <div class="main__information__product__person">
                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/36/36"
                                 alt="">
                            <div class="main__information__product__person__details">
                                <h3>Aliza Webber</h3>
                                <p>Interior designer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Designed in 2020 by Aliza Webber</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné eliminando el `position: relative;` del contenedor principal donde se encuentran las imágenes con las superposiciones.